# When Click an Application Icon On Taskbar, Jump To the Workspace It was First Created

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, .desktop, workspaces

I am using Zorin which uses Gnome.

I am attaching an screenshot first:

[image]

You can see that, I have open nemo and firefox in workspace 1.

Then I went to workspace 2.

Now when I click nemo icon on taskbar, it takes me to workspace 1. **This is the desirable behavior**.

But from workspace 2, if I click firefox icon on taskbar, it opens a new window in workspace 2. **This is not the desirable behavior**. When i click on firefox icon on taskbar on workspace 2, i want to jump to workspace 1, as I have first opened firefox in worspace 1.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution but findings.

Some programs can not open multiple instances, they will jump to the previous workspace. For example, foliate.

For those apps that can open multiple instances, you need to edit the `.desktop` file to add an action that will open new instance.

What i mean is, if `nemo.desktop` file looks like:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nemo %U
Icon=filemanager
Keywords=folders;filesystem;explorer;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
Actions=open-home;open-computer;open-trash;

[Desktop Action open-home]
Name=Home
Exec=nemo %U

[Desktop Action open-computer]
Name=Computer
Exec=nemo computer:///

[Desktop Action open-trash]
Name=Trash
Exec=nemo trash:///
```

It will jump to another workspace. But if modify in the following way:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Files
Comment=Access and organize files
Exec=nemo %U
Icon=filemanager
Keywords=folders;filesystem;explorer;
Terminal=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=false
Categories=GNOME;GTK;Utility;Core;FileManager;
MimeType=inode/directory;application/x-gnome-saved-search;
Actions=new-window;open-home;open-computer;open-trash;

[Desktop Action new-window]
Name=New Window
Exec=nemo %U

[Desktop Action open-home]
Name=Home
Exec=nemo %U

[Desktop Action open-computer]
Name=Computer
Exec=nemo computer:///

[Desktop Action open-trash]
Name=Trash
Exec=nemo trash:///
```

It will now stop jumping to the workspace where the window was first created.

This evidence for this finding is in:

https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/1236#issuecomment-832838618